# Multiprocessing in Python pandas for 300k rows

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

We have data of 300 000 rows representing workers balance histories. The goal is to add special feature counting number of refunding of penalties (which can detected by sum 500 or 1000 in `amount` column). Original "for" cycle seeks 20 hours to finish computing of metric. So I am trying to do multiprocessing to use all cores of the processor. Below is simplified data:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'id': ['4c9bc686-a93b-4ada-93db-a02630fa9abf', 'bc4e77b2-42a1-49ea-940a-6d3d7aa46884',
  '8a13271b-0896-4e32-be5e-b212ab0cd2de',  '26f9b69a-a5fa-41c6-b4df-4e1e87a90771',
  '8a6c5f8e-d25c-4175-b679-53de89222cb4',  '0ecc3dbf-3334-4061-b0a8-db5091d3c5d4',
  '9e911c0d-b897-4cea-852c-4cc900f6da5b',  '0cba22f8-267f-4a3d-bc43-1374a1c278c0',
  'ca755097-03c2-4115-8b1f-69af1d37c871',  'b3a3cc81-ef2a-49db-8c54-2afeaa233825',
  '84b627df-ce18-4517-89d6-00235733487d',  '142437b8-12e9-4aaa-aaac-f8c82fe3f3f7',
  '8129cb34-125f-4f09-af09-76aece4141db',  '186153f5-5122-4707-bdd4-760138f57e87',
  'e7e36a2b-5d61-4bc1-bffa-62c003aa42a5',  'e89de3aa-b806-41c6-a797-95b909f5b02f',
  'af77ea7f-1b10-4909-988a-e2a886f9cc4b',  'e1230239-dd9c-4d25-9d5e-850ac13773a2',
  'a9c5d61c-b456-4c58-807a-de691e61fc7a',  '78271c49-e257-40ac-b355-7ba74f75b8df'],
 'balance_id': [52427, 18088, 49180,  49247,  20950,  49247,  20950,  52427, 18088, 49180, 822,29670,10523,28668,14783,20950,13270,41691,26007,22949],
 'amount': [1700.0, 500.0,  500.0,  1700.0,  1700.0,  -1700.0, -1700.0, 500.0, 1000.0, -1700.0, 1500.0,
  1500.0,  2025.0,  2025.0,  2125.0,  2025.0, 1300.0,  1300.0,  1300.0,  1300.0],
 'created_at': ['2020-03-10 15:32:38',  '2020-03-10 15:32:39',  '2020-03-10 15:32:39',
  '2020-03-10 15:32:46','2020-03-10 15:32:47',  '2020-03-10 15:33:40',
  '2020-03-10 15:33:40',  '2020-03-10 15:33:41', '2020-03-10 15:33:41','2020-03-10 15:33:41',  '2020-03-11 06:10:09',
  '2020-03-11 06:10:10',  '2020-03-11 07:01:20','2020-03-11 07:01:20',  '2020-03-11 07:01:21',
 '2020-03-11 07:01:22',  '2020-03-11 07:02:14','2020-03-11 07:09:19','2020-03-11 07:09:20','2020-03-11 07:09:20']}
dbh1=pd.DataFrame(kkk)
dbh1
```

```
        id                               balance_id amount    created_at
0   4c9bc686-a93b-4ada-93db-a02630fa9abf    52427   1700.0  2020-03-10 15:32:38
1   bc4e77b2-42a1-49ea-940a-6d3d7aa46884    18088   500.0   2020-03-10 15:32:39
2   8a13271b-0896-4e32-be5e-b212ab0cd2de    49180   500.0   2020-03-10 15:32:39
3   26f9b69a-a5fa-41c6-b4df-4e1e87a90771    49247   1700.0  2020-03-10 15:32:46
4   8a6c5f8e-d25c-4175-b679-53de89222cb4    20950   1700.0  2020-03-10 15:32:47
5   0ecc3dbf-3334-4061-b0a8-db5091d3c5d4    49247   -1700.0 2020-03-10 15:33:40
6   9e911c0d-b897-4cea-852c-4cc900f6da5b    20950   -1700.0 2020-03-10 15:33:40
7   0cba22f8-267f-4a3d-bc43-1374a1c278c0    52427   500.0   2020-03-10 15:33:41
8   ca755097-03c2-4115-8b1f-69af1d37c871    18088   1000.0  2020-03-10 15:33:41
9   b3a3cc81-ef2a-49db-8c54-2afeaa233825    49180   -1700.0 2020-03-10 15:33:41
10  84b627df-ce18-4517-89d6-00235733487d    822      1500.0 2020-03-11 06:10:09
11  142437b8-12e9-4aaa-aaac-f8c82fe3f3f7    29670   1500.0  2020-03-11 06:10:10
12  8129cb34-125f-4f09-af09-76aece4141db    10523   2025.0  2020-03-11 07:01:20
13  186153f5-5122-4707-bdd4-760138f57e87    28668   2025.0  2020-03-11 07:01:20
14  e7e36a2b-5d61-4bc1-bffa-62c003aa42a5    14783   2125.0  2020-03-11 07:01:21
15  e89de3aa-b806-41c6-a797-95b909f5b02f    20950   2025.0  2020-03-11 07:01:22
16  af77ea7f-1b10-4909-988a-e2a886f9cc4b    13270   1300.0  2020-03-11 07:02:14
17  e1230239-dd9c-4d25-9d5e-850ac13773a2    41691   1300.0  2020-03-11 07:09:19
18  a9c5d61c-b456-4c58-807a-de691e61fc7a    26007   1300.0  2020-03-11 07:09:20
19  78271c49-e257-40ac-b355-7ba74f75b8df    22949   1300.0  2020-03-11 07:09:20
```

I try the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

dbh1['correction_count']=0
def multiprocessing_cycle(start,stop):
    for i in tqdm(range(len(dbh1.iloc[start:stop]))):
        with pd.option_context('mode.chained_assignment',None):
            dbh1['correction_count'].iloc[i]=dbh1.loc[(dbh1['balance_id']==dbh1['balance_id'].iloc[i])
                              &(dbh1['amount'].isin([500,1000]))
                              &(dbh1['created_at']<dbh1['created_at'].iloc[i])
                              ]['amount'].sum()/500
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    proc1=Process(target=multiprocessing_cycle,args=(0,5))
    proc2=Process(target=multiprocessing_cycle,args=(6,10))
    proc3=Process(target=multiprocessing_cycle,args=(11,15))
    proc4=Process(target=multiprocessing_cycle,args=(16,19))
    procs.append(proc1)
    proc1.start()
    proc1.join()            
    proc2.start()
    proc2.join()   
    proc3.start()
    proc3.join()   
    proc4.start()
    proc4.join()
```

And nothing happens at all (while the function works if I put in whole data in it without multiprocessing). What can be done?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A column of values counting number of times when amount was 500 or 1000, summarized and divided by 500. It's not that important now,the goal is to start multiprocessing somehow

Comment: I think you can do this without manually writing a lot of code using [dask](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/dask-tutorial/). The dask dataframe has the same API as the pandas dataframe but large operations can be parallelised.

Comment: I've been using [Pandarallel](https://nalepae.github.io/pandarallel/) with good results. Brought an apply function I had from 15+ minutes to just 2 minutes.

Comment: Well, if you first filter your dataframe for rows whose balance is either 500 or 1000, you will have a lot fewer rows to deal with